# Erro Netbeans 8.2 "java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'query_cache_size'"

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, netbeans

Não consigo conectar em um banco de dados MySql através da IDE Netbeans, é informado o seguinte erro: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'query_cache_size'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o erro apenas atualizando a versão do plugin do Maven